# Sync database of android app with web server database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am a noob in android development, I developed an android application using sqlite database. I have same application on web server in php using mysql database.
I want to sync the changes of whole database(including all six tables) on web server with my android app database. How do I do it?
I need to know how do i check if there is some updation in web server database and if there is some updation then how do i get those updations to my android database automatically.

Is there a way to do it without GCM and SyncAdapter?

Comment: for that u need to write your own scheduler that connects your database and send data and server is written in php performs some operation as u required

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft Syncframework is power full enough for you requirement. 
It will sync only delta changes and also resolve conflicts you don't need to any extra efforts at dev level.

You can get sample from here [Microsoft syncFramwework tool kit for android](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/)

Comment: can you provide link for android  i want to test it

Comment: for server side is it mandatory to use Microsoft technology ??

Comment: for server side you need to get more information from Microsoft website.